# Java Streams Large Datasets

Tags: java, java-stream

If I have:

```
class Person{
  String firstName;
  String lastName;
  ...
}
```

The person objects are created from a file that is read in and may contain millions of People.

The task is to create a mapping of a hundred people with the most popular `lastName`. This will be in for form of `(lastName, numPeopleWithName)`. For example: `("Adam", 23455)`.

How do I do this using Streams. I can do this easy enough using a loop, but using streams seems to be very inefficient as the only way I can think of doing it is by mapping to `int`s and then sorting and pulling of the top 100  via `limit(n)`, but this doesn't feel right.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Have a look at `Collectors.groupBy` and `Collectors.counting`

Answer (score 0):

Streams are efficient if they are used in a proper way. In your case assuming you have a `personList` as the input you can compute the `lastName` frequencies by

```
Map<String, Long> lastNameFrequencies = personList.stream()
    // compute unique last names and their frequencies
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Person::getLastName, Collectors.counting()))
```

Now, having the frequencies mapped, we can sort them by from the highest to lowest occurrences limiting the output to the desired value:

```
Map<String, Long> sortedLastNameFrequencies = lastNameFrequencies
    .entrySet()
    .stream()
    .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByValue().reversed())
    .limit(100)
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue, (e1, e2) -> e1, LinkedHashMap::new))
```